# How to parse a string json from a sql query result and map it

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json

I have a query that gives me a result but 2 columns of the table im querying into dont have normal records but they contain a JSON string (varcharMAX format).I need to parse the json given from the query result and map it

this is the mapping i have done where i get the values of the column

```
 vinDetails e = new vinDetails();
  {

   e.bundle= DataReaderExtension.GetStringOrNull(reader, "bundle");
   e.fix = DataReaderExtension.GetStringOrNull(reader, "fix")
   e.House = DataReaderExtension.GetStringOrNull(reader, "House")
   e.not_House = DataReaderExtension.GetStringOrNull(reader, "not_House ")
   };
```

While this is my model

public class vinDetails

```
    public string bundle { get; set; }
    public string fix { get; set; }
    public string house { get; set; }
    public string not_house { get; set; }
```

bundle and fix are fine since they are just a value taken from the column.
But the other i have in the model (house,not_house),
they both return a string JSON  like this

```
   {
    'Email': 'james@example.com',
     'Active': true,
    'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
    'Roles': [
     'User',
     'Admin'
             ]
             }"
```

I dont know how to map these json in order to return evrything in a

LinkedList

Comment: Use a Json parser/deserializer like JSON.NET. It's the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET Web API and later

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the json to class and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. follow the below example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"Email\": \"james@example.com\",\"Active\": true,\"CreatedDate\": \"2013-01-20T00:00:00Z\",\"Roles\": [\"User\", \"Admin\"]}";

        House result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<House>(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"{result.Email} ");
    }

    public class House
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Just to add on to this, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` comes from the [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) libraries